# Errors in building inet-3.6.0 in omnet 5.7

Tags: omnet++, inet, openflow

- make: *** [Makefile:127: out/clang-debug//openflow_dbg.exe] Error 1
- make: *** [Makefile:6: all] Error 2
- make[1]: *** [Makefile:1190: ../out/clang-debug/src/inet/applications/packetdrill/PacketDrillApp.o] Error 1
- make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is clearly to be expected as OMNET 5.7 requires at least INET 3.7.1 according to the INET download page.

Comment: I did try it the compatible version with each other, but still got the error. I moved to ubuntu now and everything works fine which is weird but does the trick.